# Script becomes too big

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to increase the number of elements in the #source div from two to three and so on. But in order to increase it each time, I will need to create a lot of new lines of code with pretty much the same data (const three=, new fuction appendIt2(), and add an extra if in the window.onload).

Maybe you can advise how can I reduce the clutter in this script and make it easier to manage?

```js
const one = document.getElementById("element");
element.addEventListener("click", appendIt);

function appendIt() {
  localStorage.setItem("append", "true");
  var element = document.getElementById("element");
  document.getElementById("destination").appendChild(element);
}

const two = document.getElementById("element1");
element1.addEventListener("click", appendIt1);

function appendIt1() {
  localStorage.setItem("append1", "true");
  var element1 = document.getElementById("element1");
  document.getElementById("destination").appendChild(element1);
}


window.onload = () => {
  if (localStorage.getItem("append") == "true") {
    appendIt();
  }
  if (localStorage.getItem("append1") == "true") {
    appendIt1();
  }
};

function clearstorage () {
localStorage.clear();
location.reload();
}
```

```css
#destination {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  background-color:red;
}

#source {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  background-color:beige;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="clearstorage()">
  Reset order
</button>
<div id="destination"></div>
<div id="source">
  <a id="element" href="#">One</a>
  <a id="element1" href="#">Two</a></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 4):

There are ways to improve your code, let's start by taking a look at the first few lines:

```javascript
const one = document.getElementById("element");
element.addEventListener("click", appendIt);

/* ... */

const two = document.getElementById("element1");
element1.addEventListener("click", appendIt1);

/* ... */
```

There is a pattern, let me elaborate, I guess if you want to add N elements there would be N `const` assignments, right? This repetition seems like your biggest problem (this in fact is noticeable in other parts of the program as well) - what could you do here to solve this?

Well, first, you could decide on how to address each element, in a generic(!) manner. For example, you could retrieve all elements inside the source div by using:

```javascript
/*
  This returns an array of all <a> elements inside the source div
*/
const allSourceElements = document.querySelectorAll("div[id='source'] > a");
```

This allows you to remove those `document.getElementById("elementX")` things, were `X` is the number of the element. Now, let's see on how you could append an event listener to each element:

```javascript
allSourceElements.forEach(function (element, index) {
  element.addEventListener("click", appendIt(index));
});
```

In fact you could do all of this in more or less one line:

```javascript
document.querySelectorAll("div[id='source'] > a").forEach(function (element, index) {
  element.addEventListener("click", appendIt(index));
});
```

Your `appendIt` function also needs some refactoring here. But first, let's take a quick look on what the current scenario looks like:

1. All elements in the source div are now retrieved using `document.querySelectorAll()`
2. The array we get from the selector is now used to iterate over and for each element in this array we call `.addEventListener()`
3. Assuming that the `appendIt` function supports currying (if you want to read more about it: [see here](https://javascript.info/currying-partials)) the goal is to return a function which receives the needed parameters when we have the information at hand (like the index/number of the element)

A sample implementation could look like this:

```javascript
function appendIt(index) {
  const element = document.querySelectorAll("div[id='source'] > a")[index];
  return function() {
    localStorage.setItem("append-" + index, "true");
    document.getElementById("destination").appendChild(element);
  }
}
```

Lastly, looking at your `window.onload` function, let's try to generalize it as well, using a similiar technique as above.

1. Fetch the source elements (the length would be sufficient, but I decided to do basically the same as above)
2. Loop over the array
3. Inside the loop we check if number `N` has the `append-N` key inside the local storage, if so we call the `appendIt` function with `N` as an argument.

This would look like this:

```javascript
window.onload = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll("div[id='source'] > a").forEach(function (element, index) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("append-" + index) == "true") {
      appendIt(index)(); // <-- Note the second pair of parentheses?! We actually call the returning function immediately!
    }
  });
};
```

So the whole refactored code would look like this:

```javascript
document.querySelectorAll("div[id='source'] > a").forEach(function (element, index) {
  element.addEventListener("click", appendIt(index));
});

function appendIt(index) {
  const element = document.querySelectorAll("div[id='source'] > a")[index];
  return function() {
    localStorage.setItem("append-" + index, "true");
    document.getElementById("destination").appendChild(element);
  }
}

window.onload = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll("div[id='source'] > a").forEach(function (element, index) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("append-" + index) == "true") {
      appendIt(index)(); // <-- Note the second pair of parentheses?! We actually call the returning function immediately!
    }
  });
};
```

This is one way to reduce the duplication and the extensive amount of maintaining when this whole script needs to be scaled. In general, try to extract common code pieces in functions - there is a principle called DRY (Don't repeat yourself). As a rule of thumb, when you notice, that some piece of code looks basically identical to some other piece it's time to extract that into a function or try to generalize it as seen with `document.querySelectorAll()`. I'd highly recommend you take a look at this MDN document about the DOM https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction

Comment: Hi, thank you for your detailed response. I will take a closer look, but I have copy-pasted the javascript part just to check if it works and it seems that it's not. Is it possible for you to send the full version? I don't want to change anything in your script at this moment as I'm afraid to break it.

Comment: Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-chihiro-uvpyq7